# Unable to get theme attribute from BroadcastReceiver's context

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-theme

I am trying to get `?colorSecondary` in my `BroadcastReceiver`, so that I can set colour to notification icon and action text. I am using following method to get value of my `R.attr.colorSecondary` from my current theme.

```
@ColorRes
public static int getAttrColorResId(Context context, @AttrRes int resId) {
    TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
    Resources.Theme theme = context.getTheme();
    boolean success = theme.resolveAttribute(resId, outValue, true);    
    return outValue.resourceId;
}

// usage 
int colorRes = getAttrColorResId(context, R.attr.colorSecondary);
```

Now the problem is, I am getting `false` result from `resolveAttribute()` call. Looks like the context provided by `BroadcastReceiver` is not able to find `colorSecondary`. How to get the desired attribute from `BroadcastReceiver`'s context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike Activity, `BroadcastReceiver` does not provide context with a theme, as it is a non-UI context. So, attributes of activity's theme are not available here. You can try to set the theme manually to this context, as follows, to get `colorSecondary`:

```
@ColorRes
public static int getAttrColorResId(Context context, @AttrRes int resId) {
    TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
    Resources.Theme theme = context.getTheme();
    boolean success = theme.resolveAttribute(resId, outValue, true);

    // if not success, that means current call is from some non-UI context 
    // so set a theme and call recursively
    if (!success) {
        context.getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.YourTheme, false);
        return getAttrColorResId(context, resId);
    }

    return outValue.resourceId;
}
```